# SignalR: synchronizing group joining

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I'm developing android app and use `SignalR` on my `asp.net` server and a custom java client [SignalA](https://github.com/erizet/SignalA). I'm facing the following problem: when the client joins some group it doesn't receive message which is sent immediately after joining. Here's a piece of code from server:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => context.Groups.Add(groupId, connectionId)).
    ContinueWith(t => Groups.Send(groupId, message));
```

On the client side I receive callback with a new groups token, but the first sent message isn't received (messages sent afterwards are however received). Trying the same thing with the official C# client works perfectly. So it seems like the first message is received before a new groups token is processed.

After long try comparing C# and java client code I haven't found the solution. I'm looking for an explanation (or code references) on how this situation is handled in C# client so I'd be able to implement the same logic in java client.

P.S. it'd be much more painless if there's a way to use official C# client with android instead of using custom java client.

P.P.S. there are some "dirty" ways to fix my issue, like putting a small delay on server after joining the group or sending confirmation message from client, but still I'm looking for a "clean" fix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no reason to be using `Task.Factory.StartNew`.

`context.Groups.Add(connectionId, groupName)` already returns the `Task` that you should await before sending a message to `groupName` that you expect the client identified by `connectionId`.

When you call

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => context.Groups.Add(connectionId, groupName))
```

you get a `Task<Task>`.

This means when you call `Groups.Send(groupName, message)` inside of `ContinueWith`, only the outer Task has completed, and `connectionId` has not yet been fully added to `groupdName`.

If you are running .NET 4.5, the easiest way to rewrite this code is to use the async/await pattern like so:

```
public async Task AddToGroupAndSend(IPersistentConnectionContext context,
                                    string connectionId, 
                                    string groupName,
                                    object message)
{
    await context.Groups.Add(connectionId, groupName);
    await context.Groups.Send(groupName, message);
}
```

If you are running .NET 4.0 you can continue using `ContinueWith`, but without `Task.Factory.StartNew`:

```
public Task AddToGroupAndSend(IPersistentConnectionContext context,
                              string connectionId, 
                              string groupName,
                              object message)
{
    // This doesn't appropriately handle faulted or canceled tasks
    return context.Groups.Add(connectionId, groupName)
                  .ContinueWith(t => groups.Send(groupName, message));
}
```

If you don't mind having the code execute synchronously you could even do the following:

```
public void AddToGroupAndSend(IPersistentConnectionContext context,
                              string connectionId, 
                              string groupName,
                              object message)
{
    context.Groups.Add(connectionId, groupName).Wait().
    groups.Send(groupName, message).Wait();
}
```

**NOTE:** In my examples `connectionId` is the first argument to `context.Groups.Add` and `groupName` is the second. This is the correct order for those parameters and the opposite of how you wrote it in your question.

I don't know why your previous code would work with the C# client but not with Java. Given the code provided in your question, I would expect either client to miss the first sent message.